# Formatting floating-point numbers without loss of precision in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, floating-point, floating-accuracy, repr

In AngularJS how do I output a floating point number on an HTML page without loss of precision and without unnecessary padding with 0's?

I've considered the "number" ng-filter (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) but the fractionSize parameter causes a fixed number of decimals:

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

I'm looking for what in various other languages is referred to as "exact reproducibility", "canonical string representation", repr, round-trip, etc. but I haven't been able to find anything similar for AngularJS.

For example:

- 1 => "1"
- 1.2 => "1.2"
- 1.23456789 => "1.23456789"

Comment: Can you give some example of input and output number values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon an obvious solution myself! Completely removing the use of the "number" ng-filter will cause AngularJS to simply convert the expression to a string according to my requirements.

So

```
{{ number_expression }}
```

instead of

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the part without trailing zeros and use that in a regex replace. Presumably you want to keep one trailing zero (e.g. "78.0") to keep it tidy rather than ending with a decimal separator (e.g. "78.").

```
var s = "12304.56780000";
// N.B. Check the decimal separator
var re = new RegExp("([0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)(0*)$");
var t = s.replace(re, '$1');  // t = "12304.5678"
t="12304.00".replace(re, "$1"); // t="12304.0"
```

Explanation from [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

```
/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)(0*)$/
    1st Capturing group ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)
        [0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
        \. matches the character . literally
        [0-9]+? match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: +? Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    2nd Capturing group (0*)
        0* matches the character 0 literally
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    $ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not considered this type of approach. It'll certainly work, and as you point out it offers full control to customize the output e.g. to include a minimum number of decimals. However, as I posted in my own answer below, AngularJS already supports what I want by simply omitting the "number" ng-filter altogether.