# How to avoid automatic decimal rounding in AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

When using the number filter in larger numbers, angular is rounding them:
e.g: The value set was **9999999999999.999** and it rounded to **9999999999999.998**

```
<body ng-app="numberFilterExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 9999999999999.999;
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
  Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/npMAgIhaIAQRsdQ0SG2y?p=preview)

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: It's not actually angular that's rounding them, but JavaScript itself. Just paste 9999999999999.999 in your browsers development console and it'll return 9999999999999.998. It's probably because of the floating point representation of the large number not being able to represent it accurately. Perhaps you might want to use some large number library

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: @JosephYoung, please provide your information as an answer.

Comment: @JosephYoung is there anyway to avoid by using angularjs filter

Comment: @JAMEELM does this solution help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28584262/5699206 I haven't used angular enough to really understand this question above javascripts number representations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually angular that's rounding them, but JavaScript itself. Just paste 9999999999999.999 in your browsers development console and it'll return 9999999999999.998.

It's probably because of the floating point representation of the large number not being able to represent it accurately.

Perhaps you might want to use some large number library such as [big number (from Ben Harolds comment)](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses 64-bit floating-point numbers, and unfortunately the closest number to 9999999999999.999 it can represent is 9999999999999.998046875, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing.

I infer from the surrounding code that you might be better off representing this particular number as a string. You'll get an exact representation without the need to bring in any library.

Comment: "use strict";var s= 99999999999999939984;
console.log(s); //Displaying 99999999999999930000 ..Is there any way we can get an exception atleast

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any exception related to floating-point number parsing precision.